# The loop over two arrays take LONG

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

Thanks for your helps,
I have two arrays: A (100k row, 10 col) and B (100k row, 12 col)

The following code (thanks to BSALV) loop through A and B => It takes really long to finish. Is there any way to speedup.

```
ReDim Preserve B(1 To UBound(B), 1 To UBound(B, 2) + 4)
     ReDim arr(1 To UBound(B), 1 To 2)
     For i = 1 To UBound(B)
          
          iSell = B(i, 3): mysold = 0

          r = Application.Match(B(i, 2), Application.Index(A, 0, 2), 0)   
          If IsNumeric(r) Then                                  
               For i1 = r To UBound(A)                       
                    If A(i1, 2) = B(i, 2) And A(i1, 1) <= B(i, 1) Then 
                         x = Application.Max(0, Application.Min(A(i1, 3), iSell))
                         If x > 0 Then
                              mysold = mysold + x
                              iSell = iSell - x                
                              MyValueSold = MyValueSold + x * A(i1, 4)     
                              A(i1, 3) = A(i1, 3) - x     
                              If A(i1, 3) <= 0 Then A(i1, 2) = "~"     
                         End If
                         
                         If A(i1, 3) > 0 Then Exit For                       
                    End If
               Next
          End If
          arr(i, 1) = mysold: arr(i, 2) = MyValueSold 
     Next
```

Comment: Both `Application.Match` and `Application.Index` when used on an array are much slower than when used against a range - if your data exists on a worksheet then run the Matches against the source column(s) and skip the Index `calls`.  Or build a Dictionary from `B`, mapping key values t indexes, and use that for the lookup.

Comment: Thanks Tim, the key in array B appear many times, i don't know how to use Dictionary from B for this case. Pls suggest a solution.

Comment: What does the code do? Maybe you have a link to the place where you acquired the code?

Comment: A nested loop over 2 100k row arrays: that's up to 10,000,000,000 iterations (if you don't hit the `exit for`).  That's always going to be slow.  If you describe your data (and provide a sample) and what you are trying to achieve, we may be able to suggest a different approach.   Also, are you using Excel 365?  There may be options involving Dynamic Arrays

Comment: How are `A` and `B` populated?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns - I think general guidance here is not to VTC here because you feel a question belongs on CodeReview.  I'm sure I'm not the only one who enjoys the challenge of speeding up "too slow" code, and we can treat "too slow" in the same way as "not working"...

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns VTC because it's off-topic here, not because it might be a better fit elsewhere, please.

Comment: Current question would need more context before it's acceptable on CR and is thus not ready for migration.

Comment: Pls see the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ES4xHhVtGH5j2SZ4Y5RmAbGIGyhypozy/view?usp=sharing

This original file is running fast because there are hundreds of rows, but when you increase the size of two table to over hundred thousands of rows, it is going to be very slow.

Thanks your helps

Answer (score 0):

This operation is *really slow* when using larger arrays:

```vb
r = Application.Match(B(i, 2), Application.Index(A, 0, 2), 0)
```

You can get much better performance just by replacing the Index/Match line with a dictionary lookup.

To illustrate:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Const NROWS As Long = 100000
    Dim i As Long, r, t
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Dim A(1 To NROWS, 1 To 10)
    
    'populate some dummy data
    For i = 1 To UBound(A, 1)
        A(i, 2) = Application.RandBetween(1, NROWS)
        A(i, 3) = i
    Next i
    
    'First your existing row lookup...
    t = Timer
    For i = 1 To 100 'only testing 100 lookups (too slow for more!)
        r = Application.Match(i, Application.Index(A, 0, 2), 0)
    Next i
    Debug.Print "Index/Match lookup", Timer - t, "*100* lookups"
    
    'populate a dictionary for lookups...
    t = Timer
    For i = 1 To NROWS
        dict(A(i, 2)) = i 'mapping second column first occurences to row #
    Next i
    Debug.Print "Mapping done", Timer - t
    
    'Now the dictionary lookup
    t = Timer
    For i = 1 To NROWS
        If dict.Exists(i) Then
            r = dict(i)
        End If
    Next i
    Debug.Print "Dictionary lookup", Timer - t, NROWS & " lookups"
End Sub
```

Output:

```txt
Index/Match lookup           9.62     *100* lookups  '<<< slow slow!
Mapping done                 0.12 
Dictionary lookup            0.26     100000 lookups
```

EDIT: changes in your existing code

```vb
Dim rngMatch As Range  '<<< added
'...
'...
Set lo = Sheets("Exc").ListObjects("TBL_Buy")
Set rngMatch = lo.DataBodyRange.Columns(2)    '<<< lookup range
With lo.Range
    .Sort .Range("B1"), xlAscending, , .Range("A1"), xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    aBuy = lo.DataBodyRange.Value2
    .Sort .Range("A1"), xlAscending, , .Range("B1"), xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End With
'...
For i = 1 To UBound(aResult)
    '...
    r = Application.Match(aResult(i, 2), rngMatch, 0) '<<<
    '...
    '...
```

Comment: Thanks Tim a lot, i will try your code

Comment: Pls see the file: drive.google.com/file/d/1ES4xHhVtGH5j2SZ4Y5RmAbGIGyhypozy/… This original file is running fast because there are hundreds of rows, but when you increase the size of two table to over hundred thousands of rows, it is going to be very slow. Thanks your helps

Comment: "Very slow" is relative and non-specific: what have you done to confirm that?  There's not enough data in your linked file to confirm either way.  Did you try making the specific change I suggested?  I don't see a change in your linked file's code...